# My wireless card isn't working with Ubuntu 14.04 on a HP ProBook 440

Tags: wireless, drivers

When I run `iwconfig` its output this:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3c8 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc.
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0e8d:763f MediaTek Inc.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`sudo lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev d4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

`sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0c
       serial: a0:1d:48:ab:ac:a9
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d0700000-d0700fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0600000-d06fffff
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter working?](/q/377050/175814) or [wlan0 not showing up… MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless](/q/504718/175814)

Answer (score 1):

First we need more information- Sorry I am unable to add a comment as this will not really be an answer but will hopefully be when we get done trouble shooting.

First what kind of Wifi adapter do you have? A usb or pci type?  Depending on that answer please paste the output of `sudo lsusb` or `sudo lspci` depending if it is usb or pci.  Also can you please paste the output of `ifconfig`.

Thanks, I will edit this answer as I get input from you, to turn this into an accurate answer. Also edit your post with the requested information please

**EDIT: The following is from a linux mint forum, I will link at the bottom.**

I was able to identify your wireless card as `Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter` so now we need to install the driver for it.

You need to install the driver for this device, please follow the instructions below. Please report back your results.

Mediatek has recently launched a working driver for their wireless device MT7630E for Linux Mint/Ubuntu. For now the only supported kernel versions are 3.13 & 3.14. So it can be installed in Linux Mint 17 or Ubuntu 14.04 with sufficient ease.

Download:

Download the driver from [here](https://github.com/mdjahidulhamid/MT7630E/archive/master.zip) (It's a modification of the original driver  for easy installation, by me)

Install:

Now follow the instructions below:

1. extract the archive in your Downloads directory
2. In terminal run:

`cd ~/Downloads/MT7630E-master`        (change the path if you extracted in another folder)

3. now run these commands one by one:

`sudo chmod +x install.sh`

`sudo ./install.sh`

It will prompt for your password. Put your password and wait to finish the installation.

After installation has been completed the wifi will appear in the network manager and bluetooth will be available for use. The driver will load at startup automatically, so you don't need to load the driver every time you reboot.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21980/discussion-on-answer-by-dylan-my-wireless-card-isnt-working-with-ubuntu-14-04-o).